# Selecting content of a textarea via jquery is working, BUT

Tags: jquery, firefox, select

In a dialog I want a textarea to accept some text when the dialog is fired, and to present it selected (highlighted) so that the user can easily copy&paste it. For this I enter the content, call select() and bind the click handler as shown here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4CK7Y/2/

Now this works in all browsers as expected, with one exception: 
In Firefox this only works on a fresh reload. When trying a "Run" in the Fiddler the text is NOT highlighted upon load, but only upon a click.

What is the cause of this behaviour in Firefox ? 
Anything I can do about it ?

Answer (score 0):

To run it when you click on the <kbd>Run</kbd> button in the fiddler, you need to encapsulate the code inside `$(document).ready()` function. Just change the code this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#payload').val("some text");
    $('#payload').select();
    $('#payload').click(function(){this.select();});
});
```

Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CK7Y/4/) here.

Comment: The embedding does not change a thing, sorry.

Comment: I am using firefox and when I press the `Run` button the content is selected.

Comment: Not for me, sorry. I already suspected that there is some bug in the components here. I am using FF 13.0.1 under a 64bit Linux.

Comment: Okay. I checked this under Windows 7 Firefox 13 and Ubuntu 12.04 Firefox 13

Answer (score 0):

When you click <kbd>Run</kbd> the focus goes to run button, thus cancelling your selection. Try realoading fiddle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Ok, makes some sense. But then I dont understand why that is different in all other browsers.

Comment: Also, when chicking "Run", the code is re-executed. Therefore the textarea should regain the focus the moment the select() is called.